# Wie fragt man wofür eine Abkürzung steht?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich frage hier nicht nach der **Bedeutung** oder **Erklärung** zu einem abgekürzten Begriff, sondern nach der **Bezeichnung für die Worte**, die durch die Abkürzung ersetzt werden.

Wie kann ich Folgendes ausdrücken:

```
Krankenhaus-Informationssystem ist die xxx zu KIS im medizinischen Zusammenhang
```

Bitte gerne auch die englische Übersetzung dieses Begriffes angeben.

---

I'm not asking for the **meaning** or **explanation** of an abbreviation, but I want to know the **denotation** for the abbreviated words.

How can I express the following:

```
Clinical Information System is the xxx of CIS.
```

I'm asking as well for the German as the English word.

---

**Edit:**

Das akute Problem ist, dass ich die Benutzer von healthcareit.stackexchange (zurzeit in private beta) bitten möchte, außer den Abkürzungen auch den Langtext anzugeben, damit man wenigstens gezielt nach der richtigen Bedeutung des Begriffes googeln kann. Vielleicht kämpfe ich da ja gegen Windmühlen.

---

My current problem is, that I want to beg the users of healthcareit.stackexchange (currently in private beta) to always add the full text in brackets for each abbreviation.
To enable me to google for the adequate explanation. That is especially important in cases when we use different denotations and abbreviations for the same thing.

Comment: Du hast in deiner Frage den Begriff "Langtext" verwendet. Ich hatte davor den Begriff "Langform" im Kopf. Das klingt zwar beides etwas ungewohnt, wird aber vermutlich verstanden.

Comment: BTW: Auf http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com wird doch englisch gesprochen – wieso willst du die Nutzer dann in deutsch auffordern etwas zu tun?

Comment: @feela Eigentlich suche ich ja eine Übersetzung von deutsch nach Englisch, nur erstens ist mir aufgefallen, dass ich noch nicht mal auf Deutsch den Begriff kenne und zweitens ist es ja irgendwie unklar, wo man Fragen zur Übersetzung ins Englische stellen kann. Auf EL&U geht es definitiv nicht, hier ist es ungeklärt und erst 'Languages', welches wohl noch etwas braucht, um als Beta zu starten wird das uneingeschränkt zulassen.

Answer (score 6):

Du kannst, wenn das für Dich in Frage kommt, die Aussage umkehren:

> KIS ist im medizinischen Zusammenhang das **Akronym** für Krankenhaus-Informationssystem.

"Akronym" ("acronym" auf Englisch) bezeichnet eine Abkürzung, die sich aus den Anfangsbuchstaben der abzukürzenden Wörter zusammensetzt.

Im nicht-umgekehrten Fall, wie er in der Frage vorkommt, spreche ich gern von der "Auflösung des Akronyms", was aber selbstverständlich voraussetzt, dass mein Gegenüber weiß, was ein Akronym ist. ;) Im gegebenen Fall kannst Du die User bitten, "Akronyme generell auch aufzulösen". Ein Beispiel hilft sicher.

Comment: Nur am Rande, in der Umgangssprache sagt man, ein Kürzel wird irgendwie *ausgeschrieben*.

Answer (score 5):

Du würdest fragen

> Frage: Wofür steht NHS?
>
> Antwort: National Health Service

Oder, um Dein Beispiel aufzugreifen:

> Im medizinischen Zusammenhang *steht KIS für* Krankenhaus-Informationssystem.

Answer (score 3):

> Krankenhaus-Informationssystem ist die xxx zu KIS im medizinischen Zusammenhang

Wenn es nicht weiblich sein muss:

> Krankenhaus-Informationssystem ist der ausgeschriebene Term zu KIS im medizinischen Zusammenhang

Bislang ungenannte Alternativen: Begriff, Wort (insbes. bei Krankenhausinformationssystem), Bezeichnung (ah, doch was weibliches gefunden!), ...

Statt `ausgeschrieben` habe ich noch `unabgekürzt` zu bieten, oder einfach `vollständige`.

Answer (score 2):

"Bedeutung" kann hier sehr wohl benutzt werden, da im Kontext einer Abkürzung die Bedeutung von "Bedeutung" klar ist.

Ansonsten ist hier auch Langform und ausgeschriebene Form möglich, aber eben selten verwendet.

Selbstverständlich ist es aber meistens besser, die üblichen Umschreibungen zu verwenden, die bereits im Titel und Inhalt dieser Frage vorkommen.

Comment: Ich tue mich irgendwie schwer zu sagen dass im medizinischen Umfeld 'Protected health information' die **Bedeutung** der englischen Abkürzung 'PHI' ist. Bei **Bedeutung** erwarte ich eigentlich etwas was ich sofort verstehe und nicht weiter nachschlagen muss.